# How to use a module with the `test` attribute within doc tests?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I have a module which I would like to use within a code block in my documentation.

This module is only used for tests, so it has the `#![cfg(test)]` attribute which it should keep.

However, as a result, this file does not seem to be included when running tests on the documentation.

Take a look at the MVCE:

**lib.rs**

````
//! ```
//! use example::mock::Number;
//! ```
pub mod mock;

pub fn main() {}
````

**mock.rs**

```
#![cfg(test)]

pub type Number = i32;
```

This fails with:

```
---- src/lib.rs -  (line 1) stdout ----
error[E0432]: unresolved import `example::mock`
 --> src/lib.rs:2:14
  |
4 | use example::mock::Number;
  |              ^^^^ could not find `mock` in `example`
```

Is there a way to make my documentation test code use these files which are configured for tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of doctest ([Issue #45599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45599)). Sadly there is no real progress since the start of the issue (late 2017).

As a workaround, [it is suggested](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/45599#issue-269350604) that you add a feature to your `Cargo.toml`

```
[features]
test = []
```

Instead of checking for `#[cfg(test)]` you can then do `#[cfg(feature = "test")]`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. The workaround is unfortunately not really something we can do in our project, but it is good to know that such a workaround exists and we are not the only ones running into this problem.